# issue with pointers and count

Tags: c++, count

I need to build a code where it takes a 2d  array of char and checks if its palindrome the second function uses the first one to see how many arrays are palindrome my issue with the code is that every time I get count is 0; I know the issue is in the second function but don't know where

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int CountPal(char M[][5], int rows);

int pal(char* S) {
    char *p, *start, flag = 1;

    p = S;

    while(*p != NULL) {
        ++p;
    }
    --p;

    for(start = S; p >= start && flag;) {
        if(*p == *start) {
            --p;
            start++;
        } else
            flag = 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    int x;
    cout << "please enter the number of rows " << endl;
    cin >> x;
    char M[5][5];
    cout << "before test" << endl;
    cout << CountPal(M, x) << endl;
    cout << "After test" << endl;

    system("pause");
}

int CountPal(char M[][5], int rows) {
    int count = 0;
    cout << "please enter the string " << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            cin >> M[i][j];
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            char* S;
            S = &M[i][0];
            if(pal(S) == 1) count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo sorry but I am a junior coder this is what I can do at the moment

Comment: No problem, I fixed it.

Comment: i think the problem is in the S=&M[i][0] but how can I fix it ?

Comment: @TedLyngmo i want the code to test line by line which is why i made it do &M[i][0] but i keep getting count is 0 no matter what i do

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the approach. Do you really want to read character-by-character in `cin >> M[i][j];`? Are you allowed to use C++ classes, like `std::string` and `std::vector`?

Comment: no i am not allowed to use classes but I want to check line my line in which I mean row by row

Comment: It'll be very short lines. Your strings can only be 4 characters long - or 5 if they are not null terminated.

Comment: the real question ask for a function of [] rows and [100] columns and I made it [5][5] just because its easier to test @TedLyngmo

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in `int pal(char* S)` function. You want it to return 1 if a given string of your 2d array is a palindrome to up your count by 1. And anything other than 1 would be non palindrome string.
So i think you should add a return statement after the end of your `int pal(char* S)` function like this;

```
int pal(char* S) {
    char *p, *start, flag = 1;

    p = S;

    while(*p != NULL) {
        ++p;
    }
    --p;

    for(start = S; p >= start && flag;) {
        if(*p == *start) {
            --p;
            start++;
        } else
            flag = 0;
    }
    return flag;
}
```

You could even change your function to bool data type. It's more proper because you only want to return "true" or "false" values.

Comment: I haven't checked other parts very clearly when i saw your function had no return values. It could still be wrong. If it is, let us know.

Comment: but isnt flag being 1 or 0 is the thing ? if *p !=*start the flag will go to 0 and the loop with exist since its an (and statement )

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your reply. The flag carries the value for your if statement but if you don't use return, your flag actually goes nowhere. I mean when you call your function to compare some value with it, you should return which value you are going to use. By that i mean the flag in this case. If not, when you say ```if (pal(s) == 1)count++``` there is no value to compare to because there are no values returned.